# How to enable sidebar changelog in WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, webstorm, diff, jetbrains-ide

Today I added Material Theme plugin to WebStorm and I believe this is the reason behind changelist not appearing on the sidebar.
To be precise, this is what happens in IntelliJ when I make change to a specific line of code and click on the yellow bar that appeared after I removed the semicolon:

[image: changelist in IntelliJ]

The change I made can also be seen under VCS -> Local History -> Show History menu option, which shows the diff between the previous and current version of that file.

However, performing the same action in WebStorm doesn't show the changelist/diff on the sidebar:

[image: missing changelist in Webstorm]

which means that the only way I can see it is by going to VCS -> Local History -> Show History which is very tedious:

[image: diff under Show History]

I found being able to quickly revert/lookup the changes on the fly by clicking on that coloured bar really handy, could someone tell me if there is a setting in the IDE that enables that? I looked up and down but couldn't find anything relevant, perhaps I wasn't looking for the right keyword.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change markers are there for me when using **Material UI** plugin. Do you have **Highlight modified lines in gutter** enabled in **Settings | Editor | General**?

[image]

Comment: That was it, I had to check that option as for some reason it was unchecked. Thanks very much, made my life a lot easier!